# Sap Portal NetWeaver 7.4: jxl.read.biff.BiffException: Unable to recognize OLE stream

Tags: java, excel, webdynpro, sap-enterprise-portal

I migrated web dynpro java 7.0 to 7.4. I have an issue when I upload an excel file. jxl.read.biff.BiffException: Unable to recognize OLE stream

I have reference to a document "Upload Excel File With Example Web Dypro for Java" but I still have an error.

(I'm using office 2007 to save AAAA.xls (97-2003) and upload

file.getAbsolutePath() = /usr/sap/DEP/J00/j2ee/cluster/server0/AAAA.xls )

I tried using jxl.jar in project java application on my desktop, it's ok when reading excel file (*.xls)

code:   Workbook wb = Workbook.getWorkbook(new File("C:/Users/pcname/Desktop/AAAA.xls"));

But on the portal it throws the following exception "Unable to recognize OLE stream"

The code is below:

```
type of Va_Resource = com.sap.ide.webdynpro.uielementdefinitions.Resource
     ....
InputStream inpStr = null;
int temp = 0;
File file = new File(wdContext.currentContextElement()
    .getVa_Resource().getResourceName().toString());

 FileOutputStream opStr = new FileOutputStream(file);

 if(wdContext.currentContextElement().getVa_Resource()!=null){

    inpStr = wdContext.currentContextElement().getVa_Resource().read(false);

    while((temp = inpStr.read())!= -1){
        opStr.write(temp);
    }
}

opStr.flush();
opStr.close();
path = file.getAbsolutePath();
       if(path.substring(path.length()-3,path.length()).trim().equalsIgnoreCase("xls"))
{
    //call method for upload
    Execute_UploadOperation();
}

.....
public void Execute_UploadOperation{
    try{
        //path = /usr/sap/DEP/J00/j2ee/cluster/server0/AAAA.xls
        Workbook wb = Workbook.getWorkbook(new File(path)); error this line, throw exception here

....
    }
    catch (BiffException e) {
        e.getMessage() = jxl.read.biff.Biff  Exception: Unable to recognize OLE stream
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your coding seems to be fine. 
What Excel version do you use? TheJExcelApi is [obsolete](http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/) now and works only with Excel versions **up to 2003**, last time it was updated in 2009.
Use [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/) for latter versions of MS Office.